# The connection variable in mysqlli_query is not defined

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, undefined

I have the following problem: `$con` is not defined, despite the fact that I use it to connect to the database. I don't understand why that is.

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "Bar_buddy_users");
    define("DB_USER", "local_server");
    define("DB_PASSWORD","010203");
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,"010203",DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to database");
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    function NewUser(){
        $first_name= $_POST["firstname"];
        $last_name = $_POST["lastname"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $query = "INSERT INTO Users (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: path the connection to your function and make sure you call the function

Comment: Where are you passing $con to NewUser()?

Comment: question's been asked too many times. Here `function NewUser($con)` solved, then "call" the function. *Done like dinner*.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$con` as parameter to your function.

And move `mysqli_close($con);` somewhere outside the function. Once you close connection it is not valid anymore. So you have to use same one without closing, or create new one every time.

```
function NewUser($con){

        $first_name= $_POST["firstname"];
        $last_name = $_POST["lastname"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "INSERT INTO Users (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
    }
...

        mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: yeah, said that already, if not twice. Maybe OP will respond to this instead.